# fully deallocating the memory of a std::vector container

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl

From the [vector docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) it would appear that the proper way to completely deallocate a vector of values to which you have a class member pointer such as:

```
std::vector<MyObject>* mvMyObjectVector_ptr;
...
//In the class constructor:
mvMyObjectVector_ptr = new std::vector<MyObject>();
```

would be to invoke the following, in order, in the class's destructor implementation

```
mvMyObjectVector_ptr->clear();
delete mvMyObjectVector_ptr;
```

However, this appears to be leading to SIGABRT 'pointer being freed was not allocated' errors.  Is the above idiom the correct way to completely deallocate the memory held at the address pointed to by a pointer to a vector (if it is, I assume my errors are coming from something else)?  If not, what is the correct way?

Comment: It is unusual to see a pointer to a dynamically allocated vector. One of the benefits of using such data structures is to free you from manual memory manipulation.

Comment: I think there's a violation of "The Rule of Three" behind the scenes that we're not being shown.

Comment: Don't dynamically allocate when automatic variables will do (gets rid of new/delete). No need to call clear() as the destructor will do that.

Comment: Where in the linked vector docs is it implied that this would be the proper way to deallocate a vector?

Comment: The exact page I linked to seems to indicate the need for clear() before delete via implication by omission in that they don't mention in the abstract what happens when a vector itself is destroyed.  Looking at the docs for vector::~vector http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/~vector/ however yields the line "This calls allocator_traits::destroy on each of the contained elements, and deallocates all the storage capacity allocated by the vector using its allocator" which answers my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, *provided `mvMyObjectVector_ptr` has been allocated using `new`*.

Additionally, `MyObject` needs to satisfy certain requirements before it can be used with `std::vector`.

The call to `clear()` is redundant and can be omitted.

Some likely reasons for the `SIGABRT` include:

- `mvMyObjectVector_ptr` hasn't been allocated using `new`;
- `MyObject` violates the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29);
- the class the contains the vector violates the Rule of Three.

Comment: the vector pointer is being allocated via new (see my edited post).  Does the delete operator automatically destroy each element within the vector, then?

Comment: @CCJ: Calling 'delete' frees the allocated memory, but also calls the destructor of the object deleted. The vector's destructor calls delete (or the equivalent of) on the elements, which in turn calls the elements' destructors, which can free *their* resources, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I don' think your problem lies in the code you have shown us.

This line:

```
//In the class constructor:
```

suggests you are using this inside a class and **not implementing the rule of three** correctly.

A better idea is not to use a pointer to a vector.
Just declare it as a normal automatic member.

```
class MyClassContainingVector
{
     public: 
         std::vector<MyObject>          mvMyObjectVector;
                        //   ^^^^^ notice no pointer.
};
```

Now it will be created and destroyed correctly and automatically.
Neither your constructor or destructor will need any code to manage this object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dynamically allocating a `std::vector` object by calling `new` and invoking its destruction by calling `delete` will result in memory that has been internally used for holding its elements being freed.

However it would be much simpler and more reliable to follow [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and use an object with automatic storage duration:

```
{
    std::vector<MyObject> myVector;
    ...
} // <-- memory is freed here
```

when execution leaves this scope (note that it could be also caused by exception being thrown etc.), it is guaranteed that `myVector` object will be destructed and memory will be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors usually shouldn't be held as dynamically allocated pointers. They should be just member variables of your class, *in most situations* (though there are always exceptions). If they *are* pointers allocated by 'new', and simple 'delete' *should* work.

Vectors handle memory allocation for you, so you don't have to. However, if you want to truly free all the storage memory held in a vector, even if it's on the stack, there's a new function for that.

Because vector.[reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)() only expands memory, but never shrinks it, in C++11, a new function was added for the purpose of freeing the reserved memory: vector.[shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/)(). Implementations and free to do what they want with it, but you're basically asking the implementation to free the memory, so they should answer the request in a reasonable way.

You can truly clear a vector by going like this:

```
vector.clear(); //Erases the elements.
vector.shrink_to_fit(); //Erases the memory no longer needed by the elements.
```

The reasons why vectors hold onto their memory is for performance reasons, so you should only do this if you actually understand why they have memory in reserve, and are willing to deal with (or know you won't have to deal with) any performance hits that result from micro-managing the memory.